# eConnect for Payables Transaction Entry Distribution UNIT Distribution Type

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

There is a weird issue where setting a line using eConnect, UNIT distribution type causes the value .85 to display 0.8 in the UI grid. After investigating, the PM10100 table does indeed have the correct value 0.85000. There is a field in this table DECPLACS, where for UNIT types without econnect insert is 3, while when inserting via econnect is 2. If I manually change this column field to 3, and bring the record up in the UI, then it will display correctly 0.85. So Why is it only doing it for UNIT types, PURCH and other types with 2 for DECPLACS display fine with two digits after the decimal point. Anyone have any ideas, is this a bug? thank you